# Basement Framing Drifted ½" Away From Starting Point

Tags: basement, timber-framing

I managed to make a hasty mistake last night when I was putting up some basement framing on my DIY project. I didn't realize the bottom plate of a 16' section drifted ½" away from the foundation from where it started (it's 6" from the foundation on one side and 6½" on the far side). By the time I realized what I'd done, I had already let the Liquid Nails dry, fired nails into the concrete with the Ramset, and attached the wall at the top. Should I just leave it? I'm concerned it's going to make hanging drywall a pain and I'm worried I'll be able to see it in the finished project. There also might be other ramifications I'm not aware of. At the same time, I'm worried taking it back down might make an even bigger mess.

Any suggestions are welcome and I thank you in advance.

Comment: If the wall is straight(no curves/bends), then drywall won't mind.  Knowing about it you will tend to notice more than other people.  Is there a reason for the 6 inch space?

Comment: @crip659 The 6" spacing is because I was going around some pipes. It would have been quite challenging otherwise. It's just a straight section of wall. I have another ~4-5 feet to go, so if I leave it, my plan is to just pick up from the 6½" point to avoid adding a bend midway.

Comment: Putting effort into sorting it now will be a lot less time than having to sort it later.

Comment: @SolarMike that's a very valid point. Am I going to make things worse by pulling up that bottom plate that has already been nailed into the concrete?

Comment: Adding more wall, you will need a long straight edge to keep wall straight.  Will be adding about ~1/8, 3/16 to the 6 1/2 spacing.

Comment: I would cut the nails with a hacksaw blade, push the plate back the 1/2" and re-nail.

Comment: The real question is what @crip659 asked in the first comment - is the wall straight or does it have an _unintentional_ kink/bend. If it's straight, but just not on the intended line, then continue with it straight but annoyingly off line. If it's **bent/kinked**, _then_ fix it.

Comment: @FreeMan it's straight and continues straight for another ~4-5 feet until it reaches a 90° bend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave it as-is, but add furring strips to the wall studs to bring them in line.
I would increase the thickness of the furring strips in steps of 1/8" across the length of the 16' wall.
So probably:

- start with a pair of 1/2" strips
- then drop to 3/8" for the next 3
- then 3 at 1/4"
- then down to 1/8 for 3 more
- then leave the last few with none

I'm assuming your studs are spaced at 16".

Cutting these strips is probably easiest on a table saw, but it's possible to pull this off with a hand-held circular saw too if you're careful.

Now continue at 6-1/2" from there onwards.

Comment: Agreed, fur it out.

Answer (score 3):

Drywall won't be a problem but if you tile the floor and put in a drop ceiling, then you'll notice it and installing those will be a little more difficult. Whether you fix the problem or let it ride depends on your ability to live with the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I'm with the comments that say "move it". This isn't an absolute statement, though, and there's not really a wrong answer.

In favor of moving it: cutting nails/glue isn't that hard if you have a reciprocating saw and a handful of metal blades. Tile/flooring, drop ceiling, drywall, built-in cabinets/counters will all be easier and less obviously flawed if you're square/plumb.

Against moving it: it's easier now. You will be able to overcome the square/plumb issues, and it won't be *that* noticeable to an ordinary person.

Maybe the final decision will be driven by this question: "Will a flawed wall bug me forever?"